# What apache version do you use with php 5.1.0? for wamp

Tags: php, apache, wamp

Okay I have this cool script I would like to bring to life, it is called "Dboorx" it's a multiplayer strategy game. I want to lunch it on my wamp on my computer.

When running it with latest php and apache, It just makes all pages blank.

What apache versions work with php version 5.1.0?

note:  the game has specific instructions to run specifically in php 5.1.0 Latest apache is unable to run with that php version

Comment: blank usually means an error but you have error reporting of so you don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advice you to update apache and php to the last version(so download the last wamp) and if games does not run then try to correct and adapt php errors for the last version of php.

Comment: ugh! the game has specific instructions to run specifically in php 5.1.0 Latest apache is unable to run with that php version

Comment: you can go to wamp site and find the wamp distribution that comes with php 5.1.0, I am sure there is a some repository. But there are few changes betwen php 5.1.0 and 5.3, so it will be no difficult to adapt it.

Comment: One of those changes must be crucial because it causes an error. I have seen the error before. The error doesn't happen in 5.1

Comment: if it does not display th error on screen try to enable them from php.ini or just just go here C:\wamp\logs and open the error log

Comment: oh my god, I know you are trying to be useful, but I need to switch php errors, not debug the script. Rewriting 200 files and 10,000 lines of code for a different php version then the one it already works on, is a giant, stupid, waste of time.